# autocomplete with two arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, autocomplete

i want to send two argument to the **`AutoComplete`** method

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(String term,String term2)
        {
            var d = db.Cities
                .OrderBy(r => r.City1)
                .Where(r => r.City1.Contains(term))
                .Where(r => r.Country.Name.Equals(term2))
                .Select(r => new { label = r.City1 });
            return Json(d, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The **`Jquery`** of the function is

```
 $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
    });
```

the first value of the same `input` field where as the next valud is of the previous `input` field always

the **`Razor`** and **`HTML`** code is as

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sender.S_Country)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutoCountry", "Coureir")" class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Country Names Contains only space and Characters - or ." data-val-regex-pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+[-.\s]?)*$" data-val-required="The Country field is required." id="Sender_S_Country" name="Sender.S_Country" type="text" value="" />            
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sender.S_Country)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sender.S_City)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Coureir")" class="text-box single-line" id="Sender_S_City" name="Sender.S_City" type="text" value="" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sender.S_City)
        </div>
```

Comment: how to pass the second argument ???

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question then i think you need to modify your @Url.Action to be:

```
@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Coureir", new { term = model.Sender.S_City, term2 = model.Sender.S_Country }));
```

Comment: it gives error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Where do you get the error? In the View? Which object is throwing it?

Comment: if it is in the view... which object is null? You can also put breakpoint in the view and debug it...